# Change empty input border after submission

Tags: php, html, css

I want to have it so if the person clicks the submit button and leaves a input / textarea empty. I want it to change the now gray border to red (Whichever input was left empty).

My current code:

```
if(empty($_POST['email']) ||
   empty($_POST['name']) ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   empty($_POST['pref-job']) ||
   empty($_POST['username']))
{
    echo "<style type='text/css'>
            input {
                border: thin solid #e51923;
            }
            textarea {
                border: thin solid #e51923;
            }
          </style>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with php, but a much better option is to use HTML5.

The [`required`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#the-required-attribute) attribute will stop submission and highlight the field red if it is not populated.

```
<input type="email" name="email" required="required" />
```

Note that this will only function correctly with those browsers that implement HTML5, and should not be relied upon for validation. You should still validate server side. In this case, I would suggest adding a class to the input field to show that it is invalid in php - something like:

```
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $emailClass = 'validationFailed';
} else {
    $emailClass = '';
}
printf('<input type="email" name="email" class="%s" />', $emailClass);
```

For this to work, you would also need the `validationFailed` class to have been defined of course - something like in your question:

```
.validationFailed {
    border: thin solid #e51923;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Both HTML `require` and PHP `empty()` can be bypassed my `space`

```
$email = null;
$name = null;
$message = null;
$pref_job = null;
$username = null;

if ($_POST) {

   $error = false;
   if(trim($_POST['email']) == false) {
        $email = 'failed';
        $error = true;
    }
    if (trim($_POST['name']) == false) {
        $name = 'failed';
        $error = true;
    }
    if (trim($_POST['message']) == false) {
        $message = 'failed';
        $error = true;
    }
    if (trim($_POST['pref_job']) == false) {
        $pref_job = 'failed';
        $error = true;
    }
    if (trim($_POST['username']) == false) {
        $username = 'failed';
        $error = true;
    }
    if ( ! $error) {

        //passed all basic validation
    } 
}
?>

<style type='text/css'>
.failed {
    border: thin solid #e51923;
}
</style>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="<?php echo $email; ?>" /> <br />
     <input type="text"name="name" class="<?php echo $name; ?>"/> <br />
    <input type="text" name="message" class="<?php echo $message; ?>"/> <br />
    <input type="text" name="pref-job" class="<?php echo $pref_job; ?>"/> <br />
    <input type="text" name="username" class="<?php echo $username; ?>"/> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Unless you want to allow empty `space` values